# Typegoose class defined static method returns empty array

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

When I use findByUserId defined static method, I get empty array value whereas if I use the model directly it will retrieve successfully  the object.

```
    export default class Cart {
    
        @prop({required: true, unique: true})
        public userId!: String
    
        @prop()
        public items?: [Item]
    
        public static async findByUserId(this: ReturnModelType<typeof Cart>, userId: string) {
            try {
                return await this.find({itemId: userId});
            } catch (err) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    export const CartModel = getModelForClass(Cart);
    
    // RETURNS EMPTY ARRAY
     const user = await CartModel.findByUserId("asdasdsa21321")

   // WORKS
     const user1 = await CartModel.find({userId:"asdasdsa21321"})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using invalid key.

```
return await this.find({itemId: userId});
```

so I replaced it with

```
return await this.find({userId: userId});
```